# Can I change the SourceFile of a Node using the Typescript Compiler API?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I am currently trying to modify the body of a FunctionDeclaration using Typescript's compiler API. I am creating a few new VariableDeclarations, and the "initializer" field is being set using an expression that is derived from SourceFile A.

I am then attempting to add these new VariableDeclarations to the body of a FunctionDeclaration from SourceFile B, however the right-hand sides of those newly created VariableDeclarations are not printing properly when using SourceFile A as the sourcefile in `printer.printFile(...)`. Semi-colons and operators seem to print, but no identifiers or literals.

The issue seems to be the differing SourceFiles, even though the identifiers used in both SourceFiles are exactly the same.

Is there a way to either set the SourceFile for those newly created VariableDeclarations (or really, for the "initializer" expression which is causing the issue)? If not, is there anything else I can do to be able to take an expression found in one SourceFile and use it in a different one?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot move a node to a different source file since basically nodes are currently implemented as a fragment (span) of the source file text.

What you do is clone it.

The TypeScript Compiler API way is implementing a Transform. Basically it traverse the AST and you identify which nodes to replace, and return a new node instead the original. The transform generates a new sourceFile that you then can print using ts.createPrinter. These are some working examples (click the run button, and the code at the right will be transformed)

simple transformation: 
https://typescript-api-playground.glitch.me/#example=Simple%20Transformation

a couple more:
https://typescript-api-playground.glitch.me/#example=Transformation%202

this other uses ts.createMutableClone() so you just clone a node and edit only what you need: 
https://typescript-api-playground.glitch.me/#example=Transformation%203

(It's a playground made by me you can edit and run again)

That being said, I recommend you to checkout this library that probably will let you define the expressions and insert them into almost any place: 
https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph

Also, if you are using ts.create* this project could be a great help to automatically transform code in those expressions: 
https://ts-creator.js.org/

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If anyone encounters a similar issue, what ended up solving this problem (that was essentially mixing `Expressions` from different `SourceFiles` which caused issues with printing properly) was using `ts.createIdentifier(expression)`. This may not be appropriate for all similar cases, but in this case I just needed the string representation of the `Expression`s in question to print properly in context of a different `SourceFile`.